# How to fix connection with mongodb by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when I call a function in javascript from HTML file, the code is going great but at a function in javascript it is not accepted connect to MongoDB.

this index.html

```
function function2() {
  function3();
  alert("Back");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://*****-******.c9users.io:8082/api/" + "Riyadh",
    "headers": {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    var obj = {
      "city_name": 'Riyadh',
      "tweets": response
    };

    responseArr.push({
      city_name: "Riyadh",
      tweets: response
    });
  });
}
```

index2.js

```
function function3() {
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient ;
  var url ="***************";
  //count
  MongoClient.connect (url,function(err,db){
    if(err)throw err ;
    var dbo = db.db("mkndb");
    var query = { time2:"2018-03-12"};
    dbo.collection("Albaha").find (query).count(function(err,result){
      if(err)throw err ;
        console.log("count"+result);
      var myquery = { rid: "1" };
      var newvalues = { $set: {Hiscount: result } };
      dbo.collection("Test").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document updated");
        db.close();
        return;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your mongodb is available from the outside (of the server)? And also - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: yes, I am sure .when I run javascript file alone it is run but when call function3 from HTML file does not accept the statement "var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient"

Comment: If you run the file with node then the  `require` function is available. In the browser it isn't.

Comment: how can I fix it to run in the browser?

Comment: But why would you even want to run it in the browser? Everyone will be able to connect to your database. Javascript in the browser is available for everyone.

Comment: which thing can I replace it rather than use 'require'?